# Camera Roll Gallery link?! ADOBE AIR

Tags: android, image, air, adobe, gallery

I am searching for a Camera Roll link in Adobe air! A clickable link to the Gallery for Android!

It will be great if anyone know this?

Answer (score 1):

[Refer here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/CameraRoll.html)

so basically you would create a function

```
function browseCameraRoll(){
    if( CameraRoll.supportsBrowseForImage ){

           mediaSource.addEventListener( MediaEvent.SELECT, imageSelected );
           mediaSource.addEventListener( Event.CANCEL, browseCanceled );                    
           mediaSource.browseForImage();

     } else {
        log( "Browsing in camera roll is not supported.");
     }
}
```

and call that when the user clicks on your link.